# How to Use sql queries to draw dynamic chart in NV D3?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

The below code for horizontal bar chart works well but now i need to retrieve data from sql database accordingly the chart should change dynamically, so where could i insert sql queries in this code and what is the format please help me guys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<link href="Scripts/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="Scripts/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/utils.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/models/axis.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/models/multiBarHorizontal.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/models/multiBarHorizontalChart.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bar.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="chart" style="height:700px">
<svg>
</svg>
</div>



<script>

d3.json("data.json",function(error,data){
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
  .showValues(true)
  .tooltips(false)
  .showControls(false);

  chart.yAxis
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
  .datum(data)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .call(chart);

 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

 chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

 return chart;
 });
 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my data.json

```
{"values":[
{"label":"Alaska","value":3},
{"label":"Alabama","value":4},
{"label":"Arkansas","value":5},
{"label":"Arizona","value":7},
{"label":"California","value":8},
{"label":"Colorado","value":9},
{"label":"Missouri","value":31}]}
```

Comment: One way to do this is would be to replace the `var data = ...` section with a data import function such as `d3.json(filename.php)` where the `filename.php` file queries your database and echos the data to the script. More info can be found here; http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html. Have a read and see if it would work for your situation.

Comment: Can i use a json file ? how to do that , i haven't got any graph while using data.json in the code.

Comment: Data in JSON format is certainly usable. (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) and by returning the data in a JSON format from a PHP script, you can interface with a MySQL database. This isn't a trivial thing to do, so you may need to do some Googling to see how it will best suit your application.

Comment: Hi d3noob! i have tried this example http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBarHorizontal.html   the bar is not shown when i keeping json out from source.. please provide any working example that have data.json out from source......

Comment: I see a note in the comments for that page that there may be a bug in the page. The following diagram pulls data from a JSON source http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5015397.  But the method is pretty ubiquitous. and can just as easilly utilise csv or tsv (so long as the data is formatted correctly. If I read your original question correctly, you wanted to get data from a SQL database. It will be more important to understand returning the data using PHP than importing JSON. See the link in the forst comment for an intro.

Comment: Hi d3noob, Thank you :)    I referred the page its seems it has some bugs, now i my scenario i am using the chart in MVC application and my database is MS SQL server. I view is built on html 5. The above chart is hard-coded if i separated the json and load from outside means it not showing graph, please check the code and tell what am missing.  I used d3.json("data.json",function(error,data){ "

Comment: Hi, the code you have above doesn't have any reference to `d3.json("data.json",function(error,data){`. Are you referring to another script?

Comment: Hi d3noob i wasn't updated the post , now there it is please check and tell the code i keep the data.json in the same folder where the html resides.  All i need is able to use json file from external resource. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, what I have done is gone back to the original example file that is included in the nvd3 downloaded zip file.
Starting with the `multiBarHorizontalChart.html` file that is the examples folder. I was able to edit that file so that it looked like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="../src/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>

body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

#chart1 {
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#chart1 svg {
  height: 500px;
}

</style>
<body>

  <div id="chart1">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>

<script src="../lib/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="../nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils.js"></script>
<script src="../src/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../src/models/legend.js"></script>
<script src="../src/models/axis.js"></script>
<script src="../src/models/multiBarHorizontal.js"></script>
<script src="../src/models/multiBarHorizontalChart.js"></script>
<script src="stream_layers.js"></script>
<script>

d3.json('data.json', function(data) {

var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
      .showValues(true)
      .tooltips(false)
      .barColor(d3.scale.category20().range())
      .showControls(true);

  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
      .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
});

</script>
```

You should be able to note the `d3.json('data.json', function(data) {` line in there which will load your JSON file which is called data.json.

```
[
  {"values":
    [
      {"label":"Alaska","value":3},
      {"label":"Alabama","value":4},
      {"label":"Arkansas","value":5},
      {"label":"Arizona","value":7},
      {"label":"California","value":8},
      {"label":"Colorado","value":9},
      {"label":"Missouri","value":31}
    ]
  }
]
```

It is possible that this is where you were striking problems as you will see that there is an extra set of square brackets `[]` outside the data. If you have a look at the sample data that was included with the example, they are in there too (otherwise I wouldn't have known either).

[image]

Hopefully that set's you a little further along.

You will want to now check out how to use a php script to query your database, return the data in correctly formatted JSON and then call that script from the point where you initially called the data.json file.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you d3noob :) Good job :)